# find duplicate word without dictionary or counter

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a problem finding duplicate in a string but my assignment can't have a dictionary and counter. How can I achieve that?

I tried with counter, but I can't find how not to use counter and dictionary.
Here is what I have tried:

```
dummyString = "kamu makan makan makan mulu ?"

def counting(words):
    words = words.split()
    print(words)

    count = Counter(words)
    for key in count.keys():
        print(count.get(key))
        if count.get(key) > 1:
            print((f"key is: {key}, and number of word count: {str(count.get(key))}"))

counting(dummyString)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following code a try:

```
dummyString = "kamu makan makan makan mulu ?"
words = dummyString.split()
already_checked = []
for word in words:

    # Do not repeat the words
    if word not in already_checked:

        # Check all the indices of the word in the list
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(words) if x == word]
        already_checked.append(word)
        print("'{}' occurs {} time(s) in the list".format(word, len(indices)))
```

We are basically getting all the indices of a word in the list and storing them inside a list, the length of the indices list gives us, how many times the word is repeated in the list.